# how to validate file upload in drupal

Tags: files, media, forms

how to validate file upload in drupal
means,

in my form allowed only txt file, but now user also can upload image file also after change the extention .jpg -> .txt

```
function oz_workbench_moderation_buttons_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id) {
  dpm($form);
  if ($form_id == 'catalog_node_form'  )
    {
    $form['#validate'][] = 'upload_validate_function';   
       return $form;
    }
}

function upload_validate_function(&$form, $form_state){
$extensions = array('txt' => 'text/plain; charset=us-ascii','doc' => 'application/msword; charset=binary','pdf' => 'application/pdf; charset=binary','xls' => 'application/octet-stream; charset=binary','docx' => 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document; charset=binary');
$uploadedfile=count($form_state['values']['field_application_document']['und']);
        for($i=0;$i<$uploadedfile-1;$i++){
                $file_name=$form_state['values']['field_application_document']['und'][$i]['fid']; 
                $file_handler = file_load($file_name);
                $file = $file_handler->uri;
                $filename = $file_handler->filename;
                //echo $file;
                $finfo = new finfo(FILEINFO_MIME);
                $type = $finfo->file($file);
                //echo $type;
                    if (!in_array($type, $extensions) )
                    {
                    drupal_set_message(t($filename.' is not valid file'), 'error');
                    }
         }
}
```

Comment: You can define allowed extensions using #upload_validators attribute if you are using [managed_file](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7#managed_file) form field type to upload your file ... For Implementation please [refer](http://www.lilianagaete.com/how-to-do-a-file-upload-in-drupal-7/) this article.

Comment: I dont want to check the extention only, i want to check file content also, when user change image in to txt file, in that condition the file will be uploadable, i want to validate this

Comment: This isn't really a Drupal question is it? You want to know how to validate the header of a file in PHP right? Please provide us the **working** PHP code that does this outside of Drupal, and we'll be able to help you integrate it into Drupal if you're having trouble. If I've got that wrong, please can you edit the question to clarify what about Drupal you need to know here?

Answer (score 2):

If your are writing your own validation u can use finfo_file from php

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.finfo-file.php

**Example #1 A finfo_file() example**

```
<?php
  $finfo = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE); // return mime type ala mimetype extension
  foreach (glob("*") as $filename) {
    echo finfo_file($finfo, $filename) . "\n";
  }
  finfo_close($finfo);
?>
```

The above example will output something similar to:

- text/html
- image/gif
- application/vnd.ms-excel

Comment: i also used already that code. it is not working

Comment: did you log the result of the to watchdog?
If you have a result lik text/txt or something then you can use a if statement to accept or reject

Comment: i have one example:- you can try to upload txt file in facebook after change the extention .txt to .jpg, then upload in your fb account, you will can not upload, i want this type of validation

Comment: Do you know how to use watchdog? Watchdog is the logging tool of drupal. If you try the above code, log the result into watchdog. Then setup a if statement and log that result

Comment: foreach (glob("*") as $filename) {
    $fileinfo = finfo_file($finfo, $filename);
    watchdog('my_module', $fileinfo);
  }

Comment: ok i can try...

Comment: how to use watchdog??

Comment: watchdog('my_module', $fileinfo);

Comment: after using this watchdog.. what will be the reflection in the userinterface??

Comment: watchdog logs info to admin/reports/dblog

Comment: I tried this code already.. this code is not solve my problem.. please give me other refrence..?

Comment: did you get any logging? If you don't get any logging in watchdog, it means the function isn't being called. Try to get logging in your function, if that works then rebuild the code. 
function upload_validate_function($form, &$form_state){
watchdog('my_module', 'test');
}

Comment: did you solve? if so i would like to know how :)
I noticed that fileinfo isn't active in every php lib

Comment: i cannot able to post my complete code in comment box...

Comment: Update the question :).

Answer (score 0):

You can validate file type by checking MIME type or by checking the extension. So there are two methods:

1. Check if the file uploaded is actually an image no matter what
   extension it has.
2. The uploaded files must have a specific image extension

Here is the reference: http://www.bitrepository.com/how-to-validate-an-image-upload.html[enter link description here](http://www.bitrepository.com/how-to-validate-an-image-upload.html)